# Android webservice call with server authetication

Tags: android, web-services

I need to call one webservice (HTTPS) with server authetication from android. Please help me how to do it.

If I try the URL in the browser, it is asking to enter User Name and Password. How to give user name and password while consuming HTTPS webservice to autheticate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asytask class to call webservices,In Asyntask Class we have basically four methods 
1.onPreexcute:used to show that data is loading.
2.doInBackground:used for sending and loading data to and from server.
3.onPostExcute:used to after data is loaded from server and here basically UI realted Task have to done.

```
    class MyAsyntask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String responseString;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        progress.setMessage("Please wait Data is loading...");

        progress.show();

    }
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String json = null;

        String url = "your url";

        try {

            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    5);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserNAme",
                    yourusername));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",
                    yourpassword);



            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Encoding POST data
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.d("Mychat reasponse", responseString);
            System.out.println(responseString);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(string);


        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.dismiss();

        }




    }
```

you can get the response from server in Json form and according to json structor you can parse json.